# Read Data from Excel Worksheet in c#?

Tags: c#, excel

I need some way to read worksheets from an Excel file, then select what it's important, and put all the Data in a Database.

It's a job for one time only. It's an old excel file with information, that have to be passed to a Database, and which will work with an application that i have developed.

I saw many examples but i am not understanding well how it works, and which way is the best to do this type of work.

My idea is to develop some application in c# that to this process.

Comment: Exact dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235887/c-read-excel-worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ may work and would be preferable for a relatively simple table.
A traditional approach would be to use COM Interop. Here's a Microsoft page about to work with Excel using COM interop (it is for spreadsheet creation, but the principles are the same - just use different API methods to open and read data):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest using a linq provider to connect to excel. This should make it very easy to query for the information you are looking for. Once you have it, inserting into the database should be easy.

http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/

Answer (score 1):

I've used this before and it works well.
http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/

had an example handy...

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(inputFilenames[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    IExcelDataReader excelReader;
    if (Path.GetExtension(inputFilenames[0]) == ".xls")
        excelReader = Factory.CreateReader(fileStream, ExcelFileType.Binary);
    else
        excelReader = Factory.CreateReader(fileStream, ExcelFileType.OpenXml);

    excelReader.NextResult();
    while (excelReader.Name != this.Worksheet)
        excelReader.NextResult();                

    while (excelReader.Read())
    {
        if (FirstRowHasColumnNames)
        {
            FirstRowHasColumnNames = false;
        }
        else
        {
            //do stuff
            var test = GetColumnData(excelReader, 1);
        }
    }

    this.Save(outputFilename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read Data from Excel Worksheet in c#? I got the Exact solution here visit
http://microsoftdotnetsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/12/get-excel-sheet-data.html